# Calculate whether meshCollider needs to be Convex or Concave in Unity C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vertices

In Unity is there a way during runtime, when dealing with unknown user-generated shapes for which we now want to create a meshCollider, to calculate whether the mesh should set to be Convex or not, i.e. whether the meshFilter has inward curves? (It's easy enough to set this property manually by looking at it, but here I'm dealing with unknown-beforehand shapes.) Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to know? How to access Mesh data in Unity during runtime, how to calculate convexness/concaveness or how to set the Collider up once you know?

Comment: I want to calculate whether the meshFilter includes concave parts (a surface with at least one inward curve), so that I can then appropriately set the meshCollider to be either convex = true or false to create a fitting collision. Thanks! PS: Wow, already -3 downvotes -- StackOverflow can feel quite unwelcoming with the whole downvotes system (and I don't mean constructive criticism in regards to the question, which is helpful) :)

Comment: Edit: Added "i.e. whether the meshFilter has inward curves" to the question, hope it clarifies! Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted so much.  It's a legitimate question

Answer (score 1):

For each triangle in the mesh, you need to calculate its face normal.  Then for each face normal, check the sign of the dot product with each vertex to see if its behind the triangle. If all vertices are behind all triangles, it is convex.

Personally, I would just mark everything concave and move on.

Comment: Thank you! To clarify, this is for a user-generated content sandbox universe where people can shape meshes and edit vertices, and a Concave/ Convex option helps them to create precise collision for when they manipulate (touch) meshes and edit their vertices. We made it an option for now, but your algorithm could help us automate it for ease of use!